# Removing of EventHandler doesn't show any effect

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, video-streaming, kinect

I wanted to pause a VideoStream from a Kinect. The button has the following code:

```
if (capturing==0)
{
    try
    {
        // Signing the Event for Image frame ready
        nuiRuntime.VideoFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nuiRuntime_VideoFrameReady);
        nuiRuntime.DepthFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nuiRuntime_DepthFrameReady);
        nuiRuntime.VideoStream.Open(ImageStreamType.Video, 2, ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, ImageType.Color);
        nuiRuntime.DepthStream.Open(ImageStreamType.Depth, 2, ImageResolution.Resolution320x240, ImageType.Depth);
    }
    catch
    {
        Dialogs.ShowWarning("An Error occured. Check, if the Kinect is connected properly.");
    }
    finally
    {
        capturing = 2;
    }
}
else if (capturing == 1)
{
    nuiRuntime.VideoFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nuiRuntime_VideoFrameReady);
    nuiRuntime.DepthFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nuiRuntime_DepthFrameReady);
    capturing = 2;//go on after break 
}
else
{
    nuiRuntime.VideoFrameReady -= new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nuiRuntime_VideoFrameReady);
    nuiRuntime.DepthFrameReady -= nuiRuntime_DepthFrameReady;
    capturing = 1;//pause
}
```

I dont think, it is hard to understand.
States: 0, Kinect is uninitialized, do so
        1, Kinect is paused, go on
        2, Kinect is normally capturing

But: when the "else" is executed, the Image in the GUI (WPF.Image) still shows a moving video-stream. In the "else" are 2 ways, I tried to make it a break. Then there should be displayed a still picture.

Of course, I simply can say the EventHandler: If we are in state 1, simply don't work on the picture, but I don´t think, this is a clean way of implementation.

Can anyone see my mistake?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Event handlers are reference types (delegates), the one you add to the event

```
nuiRuntime.VideoFrameReady += new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nuiRuntime_VideoFrameReady);
```

is not the same one you remove from it:

```
nuiRuntime.VideoFrameReady -= new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nuiRuntime_VideoFrameReady);
```

The fix is simple, keep the handler instance somewhere:

```
var handler = new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nuiRuntime_VideoFrameReady);
```

then add/remove the same instance:

```
nuiRuntime.VideoFrameReady += handler;
nuiRuntime.VideoFrameReady -= handler;
```

BTW, the code you use in the "else" block:

```
nuiRuntime.DepthFrameReady -= nuiRuntime_DepthFrameReady;
```

is the same as:

```
nuiRuntime.DepthFrameReady -= new EventHandler<ImageFrameReadyEventArgs>(nuiRuntime_DepthFrameReady);
```

The compiler simple do the `new EventHandler<>` things for you.

Comment: This is wrong! When removing an event handler, not the passed delegate is evaluated, but the delegate target.

Comment: Actually, [`==` for delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.op_equality.aspx) is implemented to do so.

Comment: maybe in the fact, he has some mistake, but in general, it works, if i do it that way. thank you

Comment: Although this would work for a normal event handler, Kinect pre-queues events on the main thread. See http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/64e8d980-f94a-4b5e-a98c-03ecd695a7dd/ for more detail.